error on installing PyQt5 in virtual environment
Currently i'm working on a python-based Qt project in Raspberry Pi 4, using RTL-SDR and Neo GPS module. I was suggested to install pyrtlsdr and pyserial in order to read those devices, but the rpi OS doesn't allow me to do so. Hence, i created a virtual environment for these packages, and it worked, but not the Qt libraries. I tried to install PyQt and Sip packages from source inside the environment ( Sip is needed to link Qt to PyQt ), but it didn't recognize Sip. Does anyone know about this ?
so i tried to install through pip install PyQt5, but the system got lagged on preparing metadata.
i also tried to use vext.pyqt5, but the safe_load() function in yaml doesn't exist so the system used replacements, and it seems to be the error.
finally, i tried to build everything from source. So from what i read, i should install sip and pyqt5. I chose sip 6.8.3 and pyqt5 5.15.10 for this work, and i got the result like the question.
in detail, after installing:

with sip: locate the extracted directory and python setup.py install
with pyqt5: locate the extracted directory and `python configure.py ~/.{my venv directory}


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

https://raspberrytips.com/pyqt-on-raspberry-pi/

if you have a spare SD Card, you could try flashing DragonOS Pi64 version to see if you can get the application working that way. It already has GPSd support and I have run it successfully with the RTL-SDR in the past.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
